# scrapy downloading images having a CDN endpoint as it's href

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

The image I want to download is of the following format:

```
<a href="//cdn.xyz.com/download/file.jpg" title="JPG file" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default">Small</a>
```

The problem is when manually downloading I need to click the button and the file will be downloaded as usual. But if you copy the href and paste it to browser the file doesn't download and you get redirected to the main website.

Since scrapy can't work like selenium (click buttons etc..) it fails to download the image from the data in href.

Has anyone tried to download this kind of images that is in a cdn? I guess it has blocked serving any requests outside of the main domain?

Comment: When you click on the button, what is the request in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62362736/edit) to include that information, as it's likely they are creating a pre-signed URL when you click

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#reproducing-requests